# A way to get a volume level from audio file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, audio

I want to have an away to split an audio file in multiple files within a silent period. For that I searched for something that can detect audio level (for example in db) and I found nothing or something that doesn't exist anymore.

Edit:

I will use mp3 as audio format.

I don't send that in a server to a client. Just process a local file to multiple files and then do something else with the audio files

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us more about your audio files?  MP3? AAC? Do you deliver stored audio to your users, or do they stream it to you, or what?